# javascriptの引数(n: number)について

Tags: javascript

下記のコード引数を初めてみたのですが、これはkey valueを引数に取得しているという事でしょうか？

```
const factorial = (n: number): number => {
  if (n < 2) {
    return 1;
  }
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
};
```

コードの出典:

- [再帰関数が苦手なエンジニアのための再帰関数入門 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ryo2132/items/4bedeec846d0427f1ac7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 短い答え

いいえ。引数はただの数値型nです。

---

### 解説

質問文に掲載のコードは[TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)や[Flow](https://flow.org/)で型注釈のつけられたコードのようです。当該コードの場合、
`(n: number)`で引数`n`がnumber型であることを、また直後の`: number`で関数の返り値が`number`型であることを指定しています。

---

ちなみにこのコードの出典は [再帰関数が苦手なエンジニアのための再帰関数入門 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ryo2132/items/4bedeec846d0427f1ac7) でしょうか。それであればTypeScriptの記事ということになってますね。尤も型注釈を取ればただのJavaScriptですが。

Comment: javascriptと似ているのでそうかと思いました。出典はそこからです。すいません、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

このコードは JavaScript ではありません。TypeScript です。

```js
const factorial = (n: number): number => {
```

1つ目の`: number`は、引数の`n`が数値であることを示す型アノテーションで、2つ目の`: number`はこのアロー関数の返り値が数値であることを示しています。

JavaScriptで書くと以下のようになります。

```
const factorial = (n) => {
```